# Does elastic search m4.x instance type supports gp3 EBS type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am currently using elasticsearch on aws for m4.xlarge.search what I am trying to upgrade gp2 to gp3 and my question is does it supports m4 instance type referring toc this doc i see N/A for m4 in gp3 table https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/limits.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/supported-instance-types.html

Comment: This question belongs on Server Fault

Comment: may be but server fault has limited views only also i am looking to know whether it does supports gp3 or not , it's not  server failure related issue as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right!

No gp3 on m4.xlarge.search.

I suggest you switch to a more up to date instance. Is anything stopping you to upgrade to a more modern instance?

Comment: i am using m4 type with gp2 in elastic search i am concerned about the data lost lost while going to m5 and gp3

Comment: there are ways to backup an es externally to S3 outside your cluster. It's index by index and this a very good step by step description ( fallow the manual snapshots ) : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html

Comment: I upgraded es even ones with 60 nodes and there are very minor risks . Amazon replicates the cluster fully , so for a period of time you have like 2 clusters. Then when both are in sync , it's switching. Very low risk , combined with manual snapshots , is very safe.